# Adding data to a session

Tags: php, silex

Real simple.

In Silex, the documentation says to add data to a session you use:

```
 $app['session']->set('user', array('username' => $username));
```

This is works fine, but I am assigning a lot of data to the session and it just makes the code unreadable with such a large array. So, in my application I use:

```
 $app['session']->set('session_name', $array);
```

Both work. However, my application is multiple pages, and I would like to add data to the session, not overwriting it, which is what my approach does.

I've checked the source code and I don't see anything in the API documentation(I may be missing it),  but is there anything like `$app['session']->add('session_key', $data)` similar to `$array[]`?

Or is my best option to extract the session data, add it to the new data then write to the session?

Comment: @Brandon Wamboldt, why was the session tag removed when the question is about session handling? I don't understand.

Comment: Session wasn't a relevant tag, and not a useful tag. Nobody is knowledgeable about sessions. They might be knowledgeable about php, or silex, or silex sessions, or php sessions, but not just sessions, therefore the tag shouldn't really be used here. php/silex is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session api is quite minimalistic, has no functionality that you need.

The quick fix is to retrieve the current value, add to it and then set it again:

```
$foo = $app["session"]->get("foo", array());
$foo[] = $newData;
$app["session"]->set("foo", $foo);
```

If you're ready to dive into code, you may also create your own session handler that has this function:

```
class MySessionHandler extends Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\NativeFileSessionHandler
{
    public function addToKey($key, $value)
    {
        $foo = $this->get($key, array());
        $foo[] = $value;
        $this->set($key, $foo);

    }
}
```

Then thell Silex to use it:

```
$app['session.storage.handler'] = $app->share(function ($app) {
    return new MySessionHandler($app['session.storage.save_path']);
});
```